# How do I add two php conditions inside an input type radio button?

Tags: php, html

My problem right now is that I have two conditions inside my radio buttons. Here's my current code. They work when they're used individually, but when they're together nothing happens.

```
<input type="radio" name="jsEnable" value="true" id="activatejs" 
onchange="enable_link();" onclick="checkBoxEnabling()"  <?php if 
(isset($_POST['jsEnable']) && $_POST['jsEnable']==="true") { 
$_POST['jsEnable'] = TRUE  echo "checked='checked'";}?> />

<input type="radio" name="jsEnable" value="false" 
id="donotactivatejs" onchange="disable_link();" 
onclick="checkBoxDisabling()" <?php if (isset($_POST['jsEnable']) && 
$_POST['jsEnable']==="false") { $_POST['jsEnable'] = FALSE; echo 
"checked='checked'";  }?> />
```

Can someone help? Anything wrong with my code? I am trying to convert the selected button parameter into boolean and then trying to retain the chosen radio button when a user submits and the form has an error.

Comment: I don't really understand what you are trying to do.

Comment: Edited it. @GrumpyCrouton

Answer (score 0):

if i understand you want to check your checkboxes if the value of $_POST['jsEnable'] is equal to the value of that checkbox, right?

```
<input type="radio" name="jsEnable" value="true" id="activatejs" 
 onchange="enable_link();" onclick="checkBoxEnabling()"  <?php if 
 (isset($_POST['jsEnable']) && $_POST['jsEnable']==="true") { echo "checked='checked'"; $_POST['jsEnable'] = true }?> />

 <input type="radio" name="jsEnable" value="false" 
 id="donotactivatejs" onchange="disable_link();" 
 onclick="checkBoxDisabling()" <?php if 
 (isset($_POST['jsEnable']) && $_POST['jsEnable']==="false") { echo "checked='checked'"; $_POST['jsEnable'] = false }?> />
```

Comment: yes correct!! :D so when someone submit the form and then they get an error, somewhere, the previous selection they had on the radio button will remain.

Comment: I also want to turn the value of the radio button into boolean, hence the  $_POST['jsEnable'] = TRUE;  . You removed it from my code @jgop7

Comment: Tried that but it's only selecting the second option even if I've selected the first option. What could be wrong?

Comment: Were you able to see?